# How to generate a .gif from video with OpenFrameworks and OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, gif, openframeworks

I'm trying to create an app with openframeworks, which has a live camera, and when it detects motion, it starts to record the video for 3 seconds and creates a.gif.

Does anybody know how to to this?

The part of motion detection is done with OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you'll need to implement a few parts:

1. A video grabber input with `ofVideoGrabber`.
2. `ofPixel` frames from `ofVideoGrabber` can then be analyzed by your openCV motion detection.
3. Once enough motion is detected, begin sending the `ofPixel` frames to `ofxGifEncoder` until 3 seconds have elapsed.  Then save.

For concrete examples, you can check out the code included with `ofxGifEncoder` here:

https://github.com/jesusgollonet/ofxGifEncoder

In addition to the included example, you might check out this project that uses it to create gif screen grabs on OSX:

https://github.com/bakercp/ofxofxAddonsThumbnailGenerator

Comment: Hey, Icheckedthe ofxGifEncoder, but when i run it there's an error saying that it's missed the ofxGifFrame.h .... So i cant use it.

I'm using ofxVideoRecorder addon to save it to mp4 file, and after it trying to convert it to gif with ffmpeg, but i don't know how exactly work ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

`ofxGifFrame` is a struct within the `ofxGifEncoder` header. 
All you have to do is remove the `#include ofxGifFrame.h` and it works.
You will also have to modify `ofApp.h`. Change `vector <ofxGifFrame *> pxs;` to read `vector <ofxGifEncoder::ofxGifFrame *> pxs;`